# How to prevent jade/expressjs form embedding stylesheet into html?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

This is my jade file

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= V2UBE
    meta(content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0', name='viewport')
    meta(name='theme-color', content='#cc181e')
    meta(name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable', content='yes')
    meta(name='mobile-web-app-capable', content='yes')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
```

But for some reason expressjs/jade is embedding whole file into html. How can i prevent that or control which one to do or not.

Comment: What your jade config is?

Comment: i've defined anywhere, but i found problem. it wasn't jade, server was sending expected html. But prefixfreejs was converting linked stylesheets to style tags, such horrible thing to do.

Comment: Please consider either deleting this question (as it was due to a minor configuration error), or editing the question to include the details about prefixfreejs and then posting an answer.

Comment: while it's minor it's extremely counter intuitive thing and i'm sure it will save hours whoever run into this problem.